# WCF Custom Delegation/Authentication without Kerberos

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, delegation

I'm building a simple WCF service, probably exposed via HTTPS, using NTLM security. Since not all users are going to be capable of using the service directly, we're writing a simple web front-end for the service. Users will auth with HTML to the web front-end.

What we want is a way to delegate the user of the web site all the way to the WCF service. I understand Kerberos delegation can do this, but that's not available to us.

What I want to do is make the web front-end account a specially trusted account, so that if a request hits the WCF service authenticated as "DOMAIN\WebApp", we read a WCF message header containing the real identity, then switch the principal to that and continue as normal.

Is there any "simple" way of achieving this? Should I give up entirely on this idea, and instead make users "sign-in" to the WCF app and then do complete custom auth?

The WCF extensibility and security options seem so vast, I'd like to get a heads up on which path to start heading down.

Edit: To be sure, I only want the WindowsIdentity to do group membership checks. I don't need a full impersonation token, just an identity token.